# Are find results in bash always sorted by filename in ascending order?

Tags: cygwin, find

I have some code that is dependent on the fact that (until now) I've been getting the results by find in cygwin in ascending order.

Is this always the case or have I to be careful about any other "variables", to make sure I will get this result in both Windows / Linux, whatever?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `bash` is your shell (command line interpreter) and does not sort. Inside of `bash` you invoke `find`. The command `find` does not sort. For a sorted result pipe to `sort`:

```
find ... | sort
```